# Type Not declared c++

Tags: c++, class, compiler-errors, declaration, forward

Hi I am making a game for my cs class and I am getting a really weird error that I don't understand. I make a function that takes in an integer and a reference to another type I made.

The error is:

```
In file included from PC.h:3:0,
from Grid.h:4,
from testmain.cc:1:
Character.h:23:20: error: ‘Grid’ has not been declared
```

Character.h

```
#ifndef __CHARACTER_H__
#define __CHARACTER_H__
#include "Entity.h"
#include "Grid.h"
using namespace std;
class Character : public Entity{

int hp;
int atk;
int def;
char prev;

public:
Character(int x, int y, char s, int hp, int atk, int def);
int getHp();
int getAtk();
int getDef();
void setHp(int i);
void setAtk(int i);
void setDef(int i);
void attack(Character &c);
bool move(int dir, Grid &g);

};
#endif
```

Grid.h

```
#ifndef __GRID_H__
#define __GRID_H__
#include "Entity.h"
#include "PC.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

/*
Class Grid is only created once per game, it holds information about the level layout
and the population of the grid (ie.Entities).
*/

class Grid{


int sLoc[25][79];               //holds potential spawn locations
int rNum[5];                    //holds the number of spawnable    locations in each room

int level;                      //the current level, used for     reading in the maps/current level
int playerRoom;             //holds the room that the player will spawn in, necessary for stair-spawn restrictions
int dragons;                    //hold number of spawned dragons
void readLevel();               //reads in the current level from a text file in the same dir. with the correct name ("1.txt", "2.txt"...)  
void addHero(PC &hero);     //takes in an hero and adds it to the array of Entities
void addStairs();               //adds the stairs in a different room than the player
void addGold();             //distributes gold across the board
void addPots();             //distributes potions across the board
void addtheD(int x, int y);//adds dragons
void addMonsters();         //adds monsters
void checkRNum();               //fills in rNum with the corresponding     amount of tiles per room
void readLoc();             //identifies where all rooms begin and end
void printLoc();                //prints the sloc arrays, for testing p   urposes
void clear();                   //cleares all entities left on the board and takes care of memory deletion
void populate(PC &hero);    //populates the board with rng monsters

public:
Grid();                         //default constructor, no parameters necessary as every game starts at level one with no population or map
void gg(PC &hero);          //increases level by 1 (goes to next level)
void printBoard();          //prints out the map layout and the symbols that indicate which Entites are present
char boardAt(int x, int y);
char Board[25][79];         //the maps layout as well as information about which     Entity occupies a given position (if any)
Entity* population[25][79];//holds pointers to the Entities that populate the board
};
#endif
```

What do you think causes this? I include the grid header file, I thought this should be fine?

Comment: Don't put `using` directives in header files.

Answer (score 4):

You have a circular dependency between `PC.h` and `Grid.h`.

Grid requires PC, which requires Grid. At least one way around, `Grid` or `PC` won't be available yet.

Use forward declarations or refactor.

Comment: So I should do 

    class Grid;

in PC.h ?

Comment: @user3055641: You didn't show us PC.h but, as long as certain other conditions hold, yes. Give it a go.

Comment: class PC inherits from class Character, when I forward declare Grid the compiler yells at me saying 

    In file included from Grid.h:4:0,
    from testmain.cc:1:
    PC.h:9:28: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token

Comment: @user3055641: Then it's more complicated and you will need to spend some time, on paper, working out all the dependencies and figuring out what can be forward declared and where. From a glance, `Grid` doesn't appear to need any more than forward declarations of `Entity` or `PC`, so it might be enough to use those there. Rule of thumb: don't `#include` what you don't need to: pointers, references, sometimes template arguments (but be careful! it's not always obvious when this is okay and when it's not)

Comment: I am having problems with this, should I post the other files here or is this improper use of the site? I'm a little lost and I wouldn't blame you for telling me to go elsewhere.

Comment: @user3055641: No, don't spam us with files. Spend some time on it yourself. Come up with a 5-10 line testcase if you need to. Post that  here after a few days if you're still stuck. But that's not an instruction to "go elsewhere"; it's training in debugging your own code. :) Anyway I pretty much just told you what to do.